# Mongoose update conditions matching wrong object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Model Schema

```
const PollSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, trim: true, required: true },
  choices: [
    {
      title: { type: String, trim: true, required: true },
      votes: { type: Number, default: 0, min: 0 },
    }
  ],
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  url: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
})
```

Update call

```
async vote (pollId, choiceId, unvoteId = '') {
  try {
    await pollModel.update(
      { '_id': pollId, 'choices._id': choiceId },
      { $inc: { 'choices.$.votes': 1 } },
    )

    if (unvoteId) {
      await pollModel.update(
        {
          "$and": [
            { '_id': pollId }, 
            { 'choices._id': unvoteId },
            { 'choices.votes': { $gt: 0 } }
          ],
        },
        { $inc: { 'choices.$.votes': -1 } },
      )
    }

    return await pollModel.findById(pollId)
  } catch (e) {
    throw new ApiError(
      500, 'Error: Poll:Vote', e
    )
  }
}
```

I have been trying a plethora of combinations trying to get this to work. Voting +1 works as intended, but when trying to -1, the query conditions are not properly matched. I have tried `$and`, `$elemMatch`, plain object with the 3 conditions (according to the docs this is sufficient and implicitly means `and` too.

Whenever I send through an unvoteId, no matter which `_id` I choose in the array, it will always match the FIRST element that has `$gt 0` votes. It is as if `choices._id` is completely ignored, and as soon as it meets a choice that has > 0 votes, it returns that for the `$` positional param.

Is this intended? I assumed `$and` would only match if all 3 conditions were satisfied.

What I am trying to do is update the votes atomically using `$inc`, while also ensuring that when someone votes, they cannot bring the value below 0. As the mongoose validators do not get run during updates, I am trying to validate this via the query itself.

Comment: Can you try this ?  `pollModel.update(
       {
         _id: pollId,
         choices: { $elemMatch: { _id: unvoteId, votes: { $gt: 0 } } }
       },
       { $inc: { "choices.$.votes" : -1} }
    )`

Comment: @Veeram thank you so much, I had backward syntax when I was trying $elemMatch — if you post this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
pollModel.update({
    _id: pollId,
    choices: {
        $elemMatch: {
            _id: unvoteId,
            votes: {
                $gt: 0
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $inc: {
        "choices.$.votes": -1
    }
})
```